# Timestamp in log changed cultureformat from 24h to 12h during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, logging, cultureinfo

I'm writing this question in the hope that you could lead me in the right direction regarding our current logging timestamp (on some servers).

During a deployment session we noticed that the timestamp format changed from 24h to a 12h am/pm format. This change was not intervened by the deployment though!

In the printout of the logging we spotted that within the same second the timestamp changed!
e.g.

> "at 08-01-2018 10:58:11" to "at 1/8/2018 10:58:11 AM"

We thought that was very odd! At the moment we can see that this issue occurs on let say 4 out of 10 servers in the cluster. (These servers should have the same config using SCCM).

#### Setup

All servers are running a Windows 2016 standard version and .NET 4.7

#### Things I've already been looking into is:

- The Region/Locale of the service user that runs the "logging service": Is the same.
- The registry at `HKEY_USERS\<user>\Control Panel\International\` does not contain any 12h format. I've verified the service account in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\`
- The logging code is:

```
streamWriter.WriteLine(msg + "\r\nat " + DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified).ToString());
```

### Update

Latest news is that we made a deployment last night that actually made the issue disappear (for a few hours though!)..

```
xxxx: End process zzz:2640190. 1/1 at 09-01-2018 08:16:10
Insert yyy yy: Start insert xxxx where zzz =2640190. at 09-01-2018 08:16:10 Insert yyy yy: End insert xxxx where zzz =2640190. at 1/9/2018 8:16:10 AM
xxxx: Start process zzz:2640190. 1/1 at 1/9/2018 8:16:19 AM
```

Comment: Is this a windows service or an application? Is the service generating the timestamp itself (is the logging code in the service)?

Comment: There must be more than one place in your application where you are writing to the log file.

Comment: @nvoigt oh right thats matters! Its an application.

Comment: @jdweng I initally thought that too but after searching code though the solution only that one line write the msg and timestamp

Comment: Maybe the thread locale is set somewhere?

Comment: Try changing the to string to:

streamWriter.WriteLine(msg + "\r\nat " + DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), DateTimeKind.Unspecified.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")).ToString(""));

If it still does it. I got nothing.

Comment: @nvoigt That was actually also something I looked into to and that not the case...

Comment: @MortenBork Unfortunately i'm a little handcuffed because my source proprietary and my access is dotPeek ;-) But i could design a little test app though :-) To verify

Comment: You need to find out if the issue is a Net Library or the windows operating system issue.  The Net Library is usually just a wrapper to call the windows dll.  So I would start by checking the Net dlls on the computer to see if the dates of the files are the same.  The DateTime is the file :  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll

Comment: When installing a VS application on another computer you must have the same version of Net Library for application to work properly.  Otherwise, you need to publish application and install the setup.exe folder so the dlls are the same on the installed pc as the built pc.

Comment: @jdweng .NET4.5 and above the client profile has been discontinued. The mscorlib.dll is now placed here:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

The version of this file is the same: 4.7.2117.0

Comment: @jdweng 

Isn't the version (4.7) backward compatible because i think that the application might have been compiled with 4.5.2

Comment: @MortenBork 

Another odd thing here... I made a minor console application that contained the same logging code as shown in the questions text. -
- Running this with my credentials gives the right format (24h) as expected!
- Now Running it with a admin account same result (24h)
- Running it with a remote seesion with the service account (the suspect)  same result (24h)

Comment: @MortenBork part2
- Invoking a cmd with PSexec (sysinternals) with the service account same result !!! (24h) -> This is the really weird part because that should be the exact same context as the current running application that fails to write the log with 24h format and are still writing it with 12h!

Comment: The issue may be with the Windows Operating dll.  The net library as I said is a wrapper for the windows dll.  It looks like it is using the kernel32.dll : https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windows/desktop/ms724390(v=vs.85).aspx.  It is calling GetDateForm : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetDateFormat.  Try comparing the kernal32.dll on PCs

Comment: My be a registry difference.  Look at bottom of following posting : https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=19322

Comment: Thank you very much for your great attention to my issue here! Really appreciated :-)

Comment: Latest news is that we made a deployment last night that actually made the issue disappear (for a few hours though!)...

Comment: It were two different thread working on the same file. The locale defaulted on the newly spawned